# Microsoft Snipping Tool Text Actions Via Command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, ocr

Windows 11 has a new version of snipping tool with OCR capabilities(Text Actions). Is there a way to invoke OCR via command line on an existing image?

I am unable to even open file via command line
I can see option on an image to open via context menu but trying to open via command line does not work:

```
"SnippingTool.exe" "path\to\image.jpg"
```

Expected Snipping tool to open with image but it opens without image.

```
"SnippingTool.exe" "path\to\image.jpg"
```

```
Start "SnippingTool.exe" "path\to\image.jpg"
```